# java lambda expression with multiple generic parameters not compiled

Tags: java, generics, lambda, parameters

I'm coding a Excel import logic:

```
public class ExcelImporter {
    //...ignore constructor and other methods ...
    public <R> Builder<R> sheet(String sheetName, RowConsumer<R> rowConsumer) {
        return new Builder<R>(sheetName, rowConsumer);
    }
    public class Builder<R> {
        //...ignore other method
        public <F> Builder header(String name, CellConsumer<R, F> cellConsumer) {
            sheetReader.header(new DefaultHeader<>(name, cellConsumer));
            return this;
        }
        public <F> Builder header(String name, Class<F> fieldType, CellConsumer<R, String> cellConsumer) {
            return header(name,cellConsumer);
        }
    }
}
```

And on my test code I got compile error:

```
@Test
public void processSmallExcelWithConsumer() throws Exception {
    try (InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("工作簿1.xls")) {
        ExcelImporter excelImporter = new ExcelImporter(is, "application/vnd.ms-excel")
                .sheet("Sheet1", () -> new RowBean())
                .header("姓名",String.class, (cell, row) -> row.setName(cell)) // no error
                .header("性别",String.class, (cell, row) -> row.setSex(cell)) // "setSex" got error and `row` evaluate to `Object` ? why !?
                .build();
```

`setSex()` can not compile,and that `row` evaluate to `Object`, I'm so confusion that it works well at first time but fails next time?

This is `CellConsumer`:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface CellConsumer<R,F> {
    void read(F cell,R row);
}
```

And `RowConsumer`:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface RowConsumer<R> {
    R newRow();
}
```

And error:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.797 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-28T23:56:26+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/166M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project graceful-excel: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/terrason/workspace/maven/cnx/graceful-excel/src/test/java/cn/lenyar/excel/ExcelImporterTest.java:[81,66] 找不到符号
[ERROR] 符号:   方法 setSex(java.lang.Object)
[ERROR] 位置: 类型为java.lang.Object的变量 row
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Help me please!

Comment: Can you paste exact complete error you are getting and `CellConsumer` interface.

Comment: @hagrawal question is update ,sorry for chinese log

Comment: This needs more context, what is the row class that you're calling `setName` and `setSex` on? And what is `RowBean`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't specifying the generic type of the returned builder in the header methods:

```
public <F> Builder header(...)
//this returns Builder which is the same as Builder<?>
//All java can infer from Builder<?> is that the generic type is an Object.
//which makes row in the second call an Object
```

Try returning `Builder<R>` in your `header` methods:

```
public class ExcelImporter {
  //...ignore constructor and other methods ...
  public <R> Builder<R> sheet(String sheetName, RowConsumer<R> rowConsumer) {
    return new Builder<R>(sheetName, rowConsumer);
  }

  private static class RowBean {
    private String name;
    private String sex;

    public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    public void setSex(String sex) {
      this.sex = sex;
    }
  }

  public class Builder<R> {
    public Builder(String sheetName, RowConsumer<R> rowConsumer) {

    }

    //...ignore other method
    public <F> Builder<R> header(String name, CellConsumer<R, F> cellConsumer) {
      return this;
    }

    public <F> Builder<R> header(String name, Class<F> fieldType, CellConsumer<R, String> cellConsumer) {
      return header(name, cellConsumer);
    }

    public ExcelImporter build() {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @FunctionalInterface
  public interface CellConsumer<R, F> {
    void read(F cell, R row);
  }

  @FunctionalInterface
  public interface RowConsumer<R> {
    R newRow();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExcelImporter excelImporter = new ExcelImporter()
        .sheet("Sheet1", () -> new RowBean())
        .header("姓名", String.class, (cell, row) -> row.setName(cell)) // no error
        .header("性别", String.class, (cell, row) -> row.setSex(cell)) // no error!
        .build();
  }
}
```